# Is a 40 minute transfer in Munich enough time? (Schengen to non Schengen)

Tags: transit, muc

I am scheduled to fly Air Dolomiti from Venice to Munich and then United from Munich to San Francisco. Flight change leaves 40 min transfer time. Is this possible?

---

Thank you all for such helpful answers.Truth is I decided it would be worth it to call United and see what they could do for me since they changed their departure to 15 minutes earlier. At first they wanted more miles for a different route but they eventually relented and I paid the taxes only. Now I leave Venice and go to Frankfurt and catch another Polaris Dreamliner flight nonstop to SFO with a comfortable layover. Took two hours on the phone with United but worth it.

Comment: Yes. However it is vital to know how much risk you are taking. Is this one ticket bought as a single thing? Or two separate tickets?

Comment: Leaving Schengen, don't you have to stand in line to have your passport looked at and stamped for exit?

Comment: @WGroleau yes, that is necessary.  Whether this connection is likely depends somewhat on whether the traveler is able to use the EU passport line.  I would be prepared to miss it.

Comment: Keep in mind that missing the connection means that they will put you on another flight free of charge and, if necessary, put you up in a hotel free of charge. Depending on the length of the delay and the reason, you would also be eligible for cash compensation: https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm

Comment: I wonder if you made it?
I also have 40 min layover and now I'm in panick that I won't make it.
Id I buy Service guide (person who can help me on the Terminal) will thing go faster (faster for passport control etc.)?

Comment: @Petry, as you can see in the bottom part of the question, OP did change the flight in a phone call to the airline. So not a 40 minute transfer.

Answer (score 2):

Both flights are on Star Alliance airlines which means they will use Terminal 2. While your United flight will definitely use a jetbridge, it is possible for the Venice flight to be at a remote gate, using a bus to transfer you from the aeroplane to the terminal. The bus should drop you off at a main terminal (i.e. not satellite terminal) gate.

Your plan of action is to move to the middle of the terminal building where you can transfer from the Schengen (G) gates to the non-Schengen (H and L in the satellite) gates. The official airport map gives a walking time of 7 minutes from the furthest gates to the security/immigration checkpoint in the centre. In the centre, go upstairs following signs for connecting flights and passport control. Once you pass through there, you will need to navigate to your gate.

As your destination is the United States, it's possible for your departure gate to be in the US departures special area on one end of the (smaller) satellite terminal. However, checking today's departure it was actually at gate H08, i.e. in the main terminal building. Again, getting to the most distant part of the main terminal takes 7 minutes according to Munich airport's official map. Getting to the satellite (the entry to the underground people mover is right ahead of exit immigration) and to the most remote gates there should also not take much longer than that, although they do not give time estimates.

With this, you still have 20 minutes to stand in line awaiting your turn at exit immigration assuming the worst. If you hold EU passports, the time required should be much shorter. So yes, the connection is absolutely doable, when on one ticket.

Furthermore, assuming your inbound flight is delayed (and that this is, indeed, a single ticket connection), do speak to the cabin crew before landing and they will do their best to help you make it. Short connection times between Star Alliance flights is what Munich airport considers one of its selling points. Remember that Lufthansa (the airline that operates terminal 2) is also Star Alliance so in principle all Lufthansa staff present should also be available to help you if you are suddenly running short of time unexpectedly.

In addition, if this is one ticket and the Venice flight is so badly delayed that you cannot make it, it is the airline's responsibility to get you to your destination. Naturally, this is a hassle and may result in an additional transfer or a hotel stay and 24-hour delay, but it is good to keep that in the back of your head.

---

If you are going to attempt this on two tickets it is still *possible* but I would advise against it as (a) you would be on your own if things go wrong; (b) in case you have checked luggage you probably would need to retrieve and re-check it, causing your buffer to disappear like ice in the sunshine; and (c) it's readily available on a single ticket so you're buying a load of hassle for little benefit.

Comment: If the 40 minutes are based on schedule times, then one has to take into account that the second flight’s boarding will close quite a bit before the scheduled time (don’t know the specific in Munich for United, but it’s generally 15 to 20 minutes), so it is quite tight. But being a single ticket they are likely to wait for the passenger.